# Embedded Google Docs Flash in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-docs

In the last few weeks we have found instances where iframe embedded Google Docs will flash like it is being refreshed, making editing and previewing a bad experience. This only appears to happen with Chrome (at least v34.0.1847.116) but both on OSx and Windows (8.1), however not for all users.

Anyone else come across this problem and know if there is a fix in production or workaround?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is being followed here - https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/docs/NitFxrcLgwY/6s2KG71WYiQJ